# Programmatically get a CLI command's tab completions

Tags: go, command-line-interface, tab-completion

I'm working on a tool that analyzes CLI tools part of which requires analyzing tab completions

I know how to *run* a command like so

```
out, err := exec.Command("git").Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
```

but how would I get the *tab completions* for that command programmatically?
I want to be able to programmatically see the completions that would be listed from
`git <tab>`

Bonus points if you know how to hook into zsh completions!

Comment: `git` doesn't know anything about completions; this is done by the shell (bash, zsh, fish, tcsh, etc.) which use (sometimes extensive) configurations for this to figure our what can be completed where. The [zsh git completion](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Completion/Unix/Command/_git) is not exactly simple. You could perhaps start a new `zsh`, make sure completion is set up, and feed it commandline + `^D`/`<Tab>`, but it all sounds pretty ugly to me. What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @MartinTournoij So I'm working on this tool https://github.com/chriswalz/bit. The problem is the suggestions that show up in the animation have all been added by hand (effectively through copy paste). If I could tap into the completions programmatically and then create a completion tree data structure (see the data structure here: https://github.com/chriswalz/bit/commit/da623d9730f360f9ddd2585f5602e3a9eea51c22), I could then have completions for all git commands, flags

Comment: Hey @ChrisW, did you figure this out? I'm looking to build something similar with https://github.com/knqyf263/pet but it's pretty hard to get shell autocompletes inside my golang cli.. Just want to know if it's entirely impossible :D